# Android Navigation Drawer not working with Scrollview

Tags: android, xml, android-scrollview, navigation-drawer

I am developing an android app which has a scrollview layout with navigation drawer. But the navigation drawer is not expanding or not working with the scrollview. But when I use LinearLyout instead of ScrollView, the navigation drawer works fine.

this is my xml file:

This is activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:openDrawer="start">

<include
    layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
    app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

This is app_bar_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context="com.example.hotel.hotelreservation.MainActivity">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<include layout="@layout/content_main" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

This is content_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ScrollView android:id="@+id/scroll"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="10dp"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">


    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:src="@drawable/hotellogo"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Arrival Date"
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:textColor="#c0392b"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"/>

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="date"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/date_icon"
        android:hint="  yyyy-mm-dd"
        android:padding="20dp"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        style="@style/Base.V12.Widget.AppCompat.EditText"
        android:backgroundTint="#c0392b"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Departure Date"
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:textColor="#c0392b"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"/>

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="date"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/date_icon"
        android:hint="  yyyy-mm-dd"
        android:padding="20dp"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        style="@style/Base.V12.Widget.AppCompat.EditText"
        android:backgroundTint="#c0392b"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="SEARCH"
        android:background="#c0392b"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:id="@+id/btnSearch"
        android:onClick="submit"/>

</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

This is nav_header_mail.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="@dimen/nav_header_height"
android:background="@drawable/side_nav_bar"
android:gravity="bottom"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/nav_header_vertical_spacing"
    android:src="@android:drawable/sym_def_app_icon" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/nav_header_vertical_spacing"
    android:text="Hotel Booking"
    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="An online hotel booking system" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: where you close scrollview tag?

Comment: You don't have a drawer in that layout. That is, you don't have a `View` that's a direct child of `DrawerLayout` with an appropriate `layout_gravity` attribute.

Comment: I close scrollview after linearlayout @Zeeshan

Comment: Can you post the full layout code, it is difficult to understand without `NavigationView` implementation.

Comment: I am new in android development. Can you please give me an example @Mike

Comment: try http://www.journaldev.com/9958/android-navigation-drawer-example-tutorial and https://www.learn2crack.com/2016/03/android-material-design-sliding-navigation-drawer.html

Comment: please check my answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:orientation="vertical">


    <ScrollView android:id="@+id/scroll"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:padding="10dp"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">


        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            android:src="@drawable/hotellogo"
            android:layout_marginTop="50dp"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Arrival Date"
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:textColor="#c0392b"
            android:layout_marginTop="50dp"/>

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="date"
            android:ems="10"
            android:id="@+id/editText"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/date_icon"
            android:hint="  yyyy-mm-dd"
            android:padding="20dp"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            style="@style/Base.V12.Widget.AppCompat.EditText"
            android:backgroundTint="#c0392b"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Departure Date"
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:textColor="#c0392b"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"/>

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="date"
            android:ems="10"
            android:id="@+id/editText1"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/date_icon"
            android:hint="  yyyy-mm-dd"
            android:padding="20dp"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            style="@style/Base.V12.Widget.AppCompat.EditText"
            android:backgroundTint="#c0392b"/>

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="SEARCH"
            android:background="#c0392b"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:id="@+id/btnSearch"
            android:onClick="submit"/>

    </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView> 
    </LinearLayout>
    <!-- The navigation drawer ListView-->
        <ListView android:id="@+id/left_drawer_home"
            android:layout_width="240dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
            android:divider="@null"
            android:dividerHeight="0dp"
           android:background="#ffffff"/>


    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: Try this .It may help you

Comment: It will work,because it is working in my case.just copy and paste above xml and try it.@user3778886.I am attaching screenshot below see

Answer (score 1):

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
        tools:context="com.ft.parse.sms.HomeActivity">

        <ScrollView android:id="@+id/scroll"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/main_container"
                android:background="@color/colorDarkYellow">

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="250dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:id="@+id/fr_home_one">

                </RelativeLayout>

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_below="@id/fr_home_one"
                    android:id="@+id/fr_home_two">

                </RelativeLayout>
            </RelativeLayout>
        </ScrollView>

        <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
            app:headerLayout="@layout/header"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/colorWhite"
            app:itemTextColor="@color/colorDarkGrey"
            app:itemIconTint="@color/colorDarkGrey"
            android:id="@+id/navigation_view"
            app:menu="@menu/drawer_menu"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            >
        </android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>

    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>


Above code works well with 2 fragments attached in a activity with scrollable view
```

Comment: This answer could be greatly improved if it included what you did to fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to:

**content_main.xml**

```
<ScrollView android:id="@+id/scroll"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<LinearLayout
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:padding="10dp"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">


<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    android:src="@drawable/hotellogo"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Arrival Date"
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:textColor="#c0392b"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp"/>

<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="date"
    android:ems="10"
    android:id="@+id/editText"
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/date_icon"
    android:hint="  yyyy-mm-dd"
    android:padding="20dp"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    style="@style/Base.V12.Widget.AppCompat.EditText"
    android:backgroundTint="#c0392b"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Departure Date"
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:textColor="#c0392b"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"/>

<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="date"
    android:ems="10"
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/date_icon"
    android:hint="  yyyy-mm-dd"
    android:padding="20dp"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    style="@style/Base.V12.Widget.AppCompat.EditText"
    android:backgroundTint="#c0392b"/>

<Button
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="SEARCH"
    android:background="#c0392b"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:id="@+id/btnSearch"
    android:onClick="submit"/>
```

I have removed the `DrawerLayout` from this file because it is not required here, please try this code and let me know if you have any issue on same.

Answer (score 0):

I used your layout and modified it and its working check i attached my screenshot

[image]

**Here is the code**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:orientation="vertical">


    <ScrollView android:id="@+id/scroll"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:padding="10dp"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">


        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            android:src="@drawable/hotellogo"
            android:layout_marginTop="50dp"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Arrival Date"
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:textColor="#c0392b"
            android:layout_marginTop="50dp"/>

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="date"
            android:ems="10"
            android:id="@+id/editText"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/date_icon"
            android:hint="  yyyy-mm-dd"
            android:padding="20dp"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            style="@style/Base.V12.Widget.AppCompat.EditText"
            android:backgroundTint="#c0392b"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Departure Date"
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:textColor="#c0392b"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"/>

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="date"
            android:ems="10"
            android:id="@+id/editText1"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/date_icon"
            android:hint="  yyyy-mm-dd"
            android:padding="20dp"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            style="@style/Base.V12.Widget.AppCompat.EditText"
            android:backgroundTint="#c0392b"/>

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="SEARCH"
            android:background="#c0392b"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:id="@+id/btnSearch"
            android:onClick="submit"/>

    </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView> 
    </LinearLayout>
    <!-- The navigation drawer ListView-->
        <ListView android:id="@+id/left_drawer_home"
            android:layout_width="240dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
            android:divider="@null"
            android:dividerHeight="0dp"
           android:background="#ffffff"/>


    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use NestedScrollView instead of ScrollView

```
   <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:id="@+id/nScrollView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true">

    <FrameLayout ...>
       <ListView ... />
    </FrameLayout >
</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```